# String with email format turns into Hyperlink

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, string

Hi this probably is an easy question but i cant find information about how to solve it i have a table with a field named Email and the values are of type string but the problem is that mvc or the browser automatically changes that string email into Hyperlink as shown in the following picture

[image]

when i inspect the element it is an hyperlink:

```
<a href="mailto:lacubana@la.com">lacubana@la.com</a>
```

what can i do to only display the emails as string? i don't want that information to be in hyperlink format. thanks very much

Edited: here is my code of the view

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
    <tr>
        <th>Email</th>
        <th>Contraseña</th>
        <th>NickName</th>
        <th>TipoUsuario</th>
        <th>Acciones</th>
    </tr>
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Email)</td>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Contraseña)</td>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.NickName)</td>
            @if (item.TipoUsuario == 1)
            {
                <td>Administrador</td>
            }
            else
            {
                <td>Vendedor</td>
            }


            <td>
                @Html.ActionLink("Editar", "EditarUsuario", new { id = item.IdUser }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Eliminar", "EliminarUsuario", new { id = item.IdUser })
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

and here is the code of my controller:

```
IList<Usuario> UsuarioList = new List<Usuario>();
                    var query = from usu in database.ReportingUsersT
                                where usu.Activo == 1
                                select usu;
                    var listdata = query.ToList();

                    foreach (var Usuariodata in listdata)
                    {
                        UsuarioList.Add(new Usuario()
                        {
                            IdUser = Usuariodata.IdUser,
                            Email = Usuariodata.Email,
                            Contraseña = Usuariodata.Contraseña,
                            NickName = Usuariodata.NickName,
                            TipoUsuario = Usuariodata.TipoUsuario

                        });
                    }

                    return View(UsuarioList);
```

Comment: How are you displaying the values in MVC?  What does your view look like?

Comment: I don't think the browser is automatically doing this, can you post the view that is producing the table?

Comment: hi thanks i updated my asnwer, please see my edit, thank you both

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`@Html.DisplayFor(...)` is determining that the text is an email and is wrapping it in a link.  You can simply use

```
<td>@item.Email</td>
```

to display it as text